# Как сделать закрытие всплывающего окна при нажатии на область вне окна?

Tags: javascript

Использую всплывающее окно, закрытие которого происходит только при нажатии кнопки с классом close. Как можно сделать, чтобы окно закрывалось и при нажатии на область экрана вне окна?

HTML:

```
<div id="dim">
<div class="msgbox">
Контент окна
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#dim
{
    position: fixed; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index: 100; 
    background: url('img/dim.png'); 
    display: none; 
}

.msgbox
{ 
    position: fixed; 
    width: 385px; 
    height: 240px; 
    z-index: 200; 
    background-color: #ebf1f2; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-top: -125px; 
    margin-left: -183px;
}

.msgbox img 
{
    border: none;
}

.close
{ 
    position: relative; 
    top: -13px; 
    right: -13px; 
    float: right; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $("#dim").css("height", $(document).height());

            $(".alert").click(function(){
                $("#dim").fadeIn();
                return false;
            });

            $(".close").click(function(){
                $("#dim").fadeOut();
                return false;
            });

        });

        $(window).bind("resize", function(){
            $("#dim").css("height", $(window).height());
        });
```

Comment: повесьте click который на close ещё и на #dim

Comment: Да, так работает, но получается, что я если и по окну щёлкаю, то оно закрывается. Хотелось бы, чтобы закрывалось только при клике по области внешней от окна, только по фону.

Comment: разместите окно модальное вне #dim; или проверяйте кто был target события

Comment: ОК. Спасибо.